# Separating single input line by colons

Tags: java, regex, string, newline

So, here's my question:

I have to ask a user to input his address, with each section being separated by colons. Input would be a single line such as this:

```
19 Wave Street: Austin: Texas: 16543
```

Then I have to take that input and display it as output using "\n". The output should be displayed as four separate lines:

```
19 Wave Street 
Austin
Texas
16543
```

I've seen people split strings but only when they already had a set string, not one that was based off user input. Also, I have to use the colons as markers to know when to print a new line. I've written this:

package address;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Address 
{

public static void main(String[] args)
    {

```
    Scanner input =  new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println ("Enter your street adress, city, state, and zip" +
            "code all followed by colons."); 

    String one = input.nextLine(); 

String[] result = one.split("\\s");
    for (String result1 : result) {
        System.out.println(result1);

    }
```

}
}

but it ends up printing only after every white space and not after the colons.

I'm extremely new to java and I really have no clue where to go from here.

Comment: i didn't find any colons..\

Comment: Jerry, just to clarify, `:` is a colon, `,` is a _comma._

Comment: You say "colons", but your string uses commas (","). If you really mean colons, edit your question appropriately. If you really mean commas, then edit your question appropriately, and I'd recommend looking into CSV parsers; commas are tricky to parse correctly--consider an address of "123 Main street, Unit 1, Austin TX 78701"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your input according to the below regex.

```
String[] result = one.split(",\\s*");
```

This would split the string according to the comma and the following zero or more spaces.

I think you wrongly mean comma as colon. If you mean colon then try `one.split(":\\s*");`